# How To Convert Jenkins String Parameter To Terraform Map Variable? (Invalid number literal)

Tags: jenkins, terraform, jenkins-pipeline, jenkinsfile, infrastructure-as-code

Edit (8/16/2023): I figured it out!

I'm trying to pass string parameter(s) to a Terraform map variable, but receiving error "Invalid number literal".

Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    parameters {
        string(name: 'IP1', defaultValue: '', description: 'Enter first IP address')
    }
    
    stages {
        stage('Git Checkout') {
            steps {
                git branch: 'branch1', credentialsId: '', url: 'http://<redacted>.git'
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy Terraform') {
            steps {
                script {
                        dir('Linux') {
                                sh """
                                terraform init
                                terraform plan
                                terraform apply -var 'vms=${params.IP1}' \
                                --auto-approve
                                """
                            }
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

variables.tf

```
variable "vm_map" {
  type = map(object({
    name = string
    ip   = string
  }))
  default = {
    "first" = {
      name = "ubuntu-jenkins1"
      ip   = "172.30.100.160"
    }
    "second" = {
      name = "ubuntu-jenkins2"
      ip   = "172.30.100.161"
    }
    "third" = {
      name = "ubuntu-jenkins3"
      ip   = "172.30.100.162"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! You can substitute 'vm1' for any value that identifies the first map object.

```
terraform apply -var vms='''{vm1: {name: "ubuntu",ip: "${params.IP1}"}}''' --auto-approve
```

If you also wanted to add a name string parameter for the vm name, it would look like

```
terraform apply -var vms='''{vm1: {name: "${params.VM_NAME1}",ip: "${params.IP1}"}}''' --auto-approve
```

I will leave this in case someone else runs into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the terraform apply for multiple vm's

```
terraform apply -var 'vm_map={"first": {"name": "ubuntu-jenkins1", "ip": "172.30.100.160"}, \
                                                          "second": {"name": "ubuntu-jenkins2", "ip": "172.30.100.161"}, \
                                                          "third": {"name": "ubuntu-jenkins3", "ip": "172.30.100.162"}}' --auto-approve
```